# "Fast Pimpl": aligned storage instead of the pointer, special member functions

Tags: c++

I have attempted to implement a "fast Pimpl" idiom based on the [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkPTreWiglk) [slides](https://apolukhin.github.io/presentations/Taxi%20C++%20Tricks%20v1.2.pdf) [and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71828288/why-is-stdaligned-storage-to-be-deprecated-in-c23-and-what-to-use-instead) [further](https://whereswalden.com/2017/02/27/a-pitfall-in-c-low-level-object-creation-and-storage-and-how-to-avoid-it/) [sources](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage), which is essentially an aligned storage of some size that can be used as a drop-in replacement for `std::unique_ptr` when implementing the Pimpl idiom:

```cpp
// ...
private:
  // std::unique_ptr<Impl> pimpl_; // allocation and pointer redirection is required
  // versus:
  FastPimpl<Impl, implSize, implAlignment> pimpl_; // no allocation, no redirection
  // BUT: size and alignment of Impl must be provided (manually or via build system)
```

The implementation:

```cpp
template <typename T, std::size_t Size, std::size_t Alignment> class FastPimpl {
  public:
    template <typename... Args,
              typename = std::enable_if<not(sizeof...(Args) == 1 and
                                            std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<T, Args>...>)>>
    explicit FastPimpl(Args&&... args) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<T, Args&&...>) {
        validate<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>();
        std::cerr << "ctor\n";
        new (pimpl()) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    FastPimpl(FastPimpl const& other) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T>) {
        std::cerr << "copy ctor\n";
        new (pimpl()) T(*other.pimpl());
    }

    FastPimpl& operator=(FastPimpl const& rhs) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable_v<T>) {
        std::cerr << "copy assign\n";
        if (&rhs != this) {
            std::destroy_at(pimpl());
            new (pimpl()) T(*rhs.pimpl());
        }
        return *this;
    }

    FastPimpl(FastPimpl&& other) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T>) {
        std::cerr << "move ctor\n";
        new (pimpl()) T(std::move(*other.pimpl()));
    }

    FastPimpl& operator=(FastPimpl&& rhs) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<T>) {
        std::cerr << "move assign\n";
        if (&rhs != this) {
            std::destroy_at(pimpl());
            new (pimpl()) T(std::move(*rhs.pimpl()));
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~FastPimpl() noexcept { std::destroy_at(pimpl()); }

    T* operator->() noexcept { return pimpl(); }
    T const* operator->() const noexcept { return pimpl(); }
    T& operator*() noexcept { return *pimpl(); }
    T const& operator*() const noexcept { return *pimpl(); }

  private:
    T* pimpl() noexcept { return std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data_)); }
    T const* pimpl() const noexcept { return std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T const*>(&data_)); }

    template <std::size_t ActualSize, std::size_t ActualAlignment> static void validate() noexcept {
        // Compiler suggests correct values.
        static_assert(Size == ActualSize, "Size and sizeof(T) mismatch");
        static_assert(Alignment == ActualAlignment, "Alignment and alignof(T) mismatch");
    }

    alignas(Alignment) std::byte data_[Size];
};
```

An simple (but wordy) runnable example of pimpl'ing Boost.Graph can be found [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Pq6ME6jrG).

Perhaps copy/move assign operators can be implemented better. The problem I see is that they do not give even the basic exception guarantee. If `T`'s copy/move constructor throws, then `data_` is in undefined state, because the `T` object representation was deallocated, and no new valid representation emplaced.

On the other hand, as I read in [the article](https://whereswalden.com/2017/02/27/a-pitfall-in-c-low-level-object-creation-and-storage-and-how-to-avoid-it/), the contents of `data_` can only be accessed in terms of `T`, which makes it UB to copy between `std::byte` objects, unless `T` is `trivially_copyable`, in which case one can use `memcpy` without invoking UB. So, based on my understanding, I am not allowed to allocate a temporary `std::byte` object and place-new a copy/move-constructed `T` object into it, and if it succeeds (doesn't throw), move object from temporary storage to `data_`. Again, unless `T` is `trivially_copyable`, in which case I am allowed to `memcpy` contents of temporary object into `data_`. I imagine something like:

```cpp
// Basic exception safety: if copy ctor throws, data_ still has valid state.
alignas(Alignment) std::byte tmp[Size];
new (std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(&tmp))) T(*rhs.pimpl());
std::destroy_at(pimpl());
if constexpr (std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>) {
    std::memcpy(pimpl(), std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(&tmp)), Size);
} else {
    // ???
    // move from &tmp into pimpl()
}
```

I understand the topic of placement new, memory laundering and strict aliasing rather superficially to use with confidence. If you happen to know any comprehensive guide besides many [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68869404/why-is-stdlaunder-required-here) [Q&A's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68863124/is-this-strict-aliasing-violation-can-any-type-pointer-alias-a-char-pointer), please share.

Comment: [Please embed the **full** code to be reviewed directly in the question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3653/231235).

Comment: I’m not sure why the exception guarantee is a problem. If it is, you can restrict `T` to be `std::nothrow_copy_constructible` from `<type_traits>`.

Comment: Your class is not really moveable, but you might add a move constructor just to be able to move the elements. These constructors should probably use `std::copy` and `std::move` from `<algorithm>`.

Comment: @JimmyHu the code to be reviewed is in the question in full. An additional elaborate example, which might be useful, but not necessary, to understand how the code works is provided in a godbolt link.

Comment: @Davislor re: not movable: any chance that `T` contains an optimized move assign/ctor (as opposed to copy assign/ctor)? In this case isn't it preferable to enable value semantics on the fastpiml wrapper to make it a "good" class member, so that the classes that include this wapper (pimpl classes) can =default their special members? That was my idea.

Comment: @Davislor re: why exception guarantee is the problem. Well, because to circumvent the case when you first delete the storage and then find out that allocation/object construction failed (which leaves object in broken state), the usual implementation is to allocate and construct an object first, then move the object into old storage, and destroy the temporarily allocated storage, of course with the help of RAII. In case of placement new, I don't really know how to "emplace" stateful non-trivially-copyable objects other than via copy constructing, hence the latter part of the question.

Comment: Although later after asking this question I realized that the copy-triviality is also under a big question mark, because `T` is actually never formally trivially-copyable. Why? Because for an incomplete type its destructor needs to be defined (even if =defaulted) in cpp file, and for the destructor to be considered trivial, it must be =defaulted in the header. So, the copy-construction is probably as good as it gets.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It has certain limitations

> I have attempted to implement a "fast Pimpl" idiom [...], which is essentially an aligned storage of some size that can be used as a drop-in replacement for `std::unique_ptr`

Be careful saying something is a drop-in replacement. Apart from needing the size and alignment up front of course, there are other differences between `FastPimpl` and `std::unique_ptr`. Some members are missing, like `get()` and `swap()`, `FastPimpl` always creates a new `Impl` in its constructor, while a `std::unique_ptr` can be empty.

However, for the purpose of a PImpl it is fine, and the name doesn't suggest it's a replacement for `std::unique_ptr`. But if you would write documentation for this class, I would carefully describe the intended use cases and restrictions.

## Invalid use of `std::launder()`

I am not a language lawyer, however it seems that many of the calls to `std::launder()` in your code might not be valid. The reason is that [`std::launder()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) requires that at the address you give it, there is already an object that is within the lifetime of that object. Therefore, `new(pimpl())` would be incorrect since there should not be a live object yet, it's `new` that is going to make one. So instead write:

```
new (data_) T(...);
```

There is no need to `reinterpret_cast<>()` the pointer. Only use `pimpl()` when you want to get a pointer to a live object, like in `operator->()`, `operator*()` and in calls to `std::destroy_at()`.

## Assignment operators

> If `T`'s copy/move constructor throws, then `data_` is in undefined state, because the `T` object representation was deallocated, and no new valid representation emplaced.

For a well-defined class `T`, its copy/move assignment operators should already ensure that the object assigned to is either valid or in its original state. Consider that otherwise, by the time the destructor is called on that object, bad things would happen. So you should be able to make use of that fact:

```
FastPimpl& operator=(FastPimpl const& rhs)
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable_v<T>) {
    *pimpl() = *rhs.pimpl();
    return *this;
}

FastPimpl& operator=(FastPimpl&& rhs)
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<T>) {
    *pimpl() = std::move(*rhs.pimpl());
    return *this;
}
```

Note that you also don't need to check whether the objects are the same, since the assignment operators of `T` should already do that themselves.

Comment: Thanks for a new review, this one is much more relevant. You are right in all regards! Except perhaps you forgot that in copy/move assign it is still required to call old object's destructor, so the placement new syntax has to stay there, too (unless I misunderstand something). I have updated the implementation in the question based on your suggestions.

Comment: Why would you need to destruct the old object? The copy/move operation of `T` will already do everything necessary to ensure both the lhs and rhs are in a valid state. So you won't have to call `std::destroy_at()` nor do a placement `new`, and consider also that one without the other would be bad.

Comment: Don't I need to call the destructor manually, since I cannot be sure what side effects its destructor has https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#5 ? Also see for example 'placement new' section of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new .

Comment: Think of it in terms of lifetime. The lifetime of an object begins when it is constructed (by the placement `new` in the constructors), and ends when it is destructed (`std::destroy_at()` in the descrutor of `FastPimpl`). However, assigning something to an object does not end its lifetime nor starts a new lifetime, it simply gets updated. There is nothing special about the `T` stored inside `data_` while it is alive.

Comment: I see now. Thank you for the explanation.